# How to read data from sp which is having multiple select statements?

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0

I have an sp which is,

```
-- States
select statusid,statusdesc,statustype,isfinal,seq, tstamp from issuestatuslut order by seq

-- PRE states
select a.statusid,a.otherstate,a.statetype,b.statusdesc, a.tstamp
    from issuestatetransitionlut a, issuestatuslut b
    where a.statetype=0 and a.otherstate=b.statusid

-- POST states
select a.statusid,a.otherstate,a.statetype,b.statusdesc, a.tstamp
    from issuestatetransitionlut a, issuestatuslut b
    where a.statetype=1 and a.otherstate=b.statusid
```

Now as you can see all 3 returns results with identical column names and for some reason I cant even change a single word in sp.

Now how can I fetch all three select statement in 3 different reader function or something like?

Comment: What framework you are using for your data access

Comment: You can get the results using a `Dataset`...the Dataset class allows you to get mutiple results into one object. https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @programtreasures ado.net

Comment: @Hackerman any other ideas something using SqlDataReader ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ... using the [`SqlDataReader.NextResult()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
    while (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //your code here
        }
        reader.NextResult();
    }
```

Comment: thanks man that is exactly what i was looking for but didnt knew how to google ...

Answer (score 2):

Try below example,

```
SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("YourConnection String");
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand();
SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
cmd = new SqlCommand("name of your Stored Procedure", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
//cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SuperID", id);//if you have parameters.
da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds);
con.Close();
```

After this you can take advantage of different (7) recordsets using

```
ds.Tables[0]
ds.Tables[1]
ds.Tables[2]
ds.Tables[3]
ds.Tables[4]
ds.Tables[5]
ds.Tables[6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Dapper`.

`Dapper` is a powerful ORM framework

using `QueryMultiple` method.

```
string sql = "[YourSPName]";

using (var connection = new new SqlConnection("Connection String"))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(sql, param: { }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
    {
        var List2 = reader.Read<CategoryOne>().ToList();
        var List1 = reader.Read<CategoryTwo>().ToList();
    }
}
```

[Dapper QueryMultiple](http://dapper-tutorial.net/querymultiple)

Comment: why use an additional framework when you already got something that works ?

Comment: Dapper is a Strong type ORM framework fast and easy to use.It's almost like the same as ado.net,when you use it.

Comment: you may be right but i am not into adding additional framework when you got the inbuilt one doing perfectly well but not saying you are wrong or dappar is not good personally i never used it

Comment: It is a fair answer, and when it was given you were not aware that the inbuilt one you were using could do what you wanted

Comment: yah i know its a fair answer thats why i didnt downvoted or said he is wrong i respect that he took time in answering infact everyone who commented and tried to help i respect you all,and the fact that i was perticularly looking for it using sqldatareader (you can check in comment section)